# How to make Spring Integration AMQP queue transactions decoupled?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp

In a **Spring Integration** application with a **AMQP** integration with **RabbitMQ** we experience unexpected behaviour.

The Spring Integration application (java configuration, dsl) consists of 3 flows and 2 persistent queues.

Let's say: **flow1** -> **queue1** -> **flow2** -> **queue2** -> **flow3**

**flow1** starts with a Message that eventually gets split-up into 50 messages (`.split()`). This first flow writes to an AMQP / Rabbit MQ queue.
In the Rabbit UI we observe a jump from 0 messages to 50 messages. Ok so far.
Then I think an 'acknowledgement' follows and the 50 items in rabbit become, so to say, visible for consumers.

Then **flow2** reads from this queue and starts processing the messages. Processing takes about 5 seconds per message. After a message is processed, it is written to the next queue (**queue2**).

The unexpected behaviour is that **queue2** gets filled up until all 50 from **queue1** are processed (250s later more or less).

I assume that **flow2**, between **queue1** and **queue2** handles all incoming requests within one single transaction. And that it will only acknowledge new messages on **queue2** after all of the items on **queue1** are processed.

I even think I experienced a case in which more items where inserted into queue1 while it was not empty yet. Then, after processing the initial 50 elements in **flow2** it still didn't acknowledge them in **queue2**. It seems it only acknowledges items after **queue1** is entirely empty.

Then **flow3** starts processing in the same fashion: it only sees the items in **queue2** after everything from **queue1** is processed by **flow2**.

The effect is that the 50 messages are processed in batches instead of piece by piece. As soon as 1 message flows out of the `.split()`, I would like it to flow through all flows individually. So, is there a setting in spring-integration, or in amqp, or in rabbit-mq that default to creating transactions on the entire workload?

Do I need to force the consumer to pick up only 1 message and create a transaction around that message? Or, should I 'acknowledge' messages individually? Or should I configure behavior in a more general fashion in java config?

My initial thought was that the DSL `.split()` logic was the reason. It adds headers like correlation id's and sequence info. (I guess this is added to allow an aggregator to calculate if everything was processed). For clarity: I have no (explicit) aggregator defined in my app.

My first approach was to clear the split-aggregate headers before inserting into **queue1**. But that didn't do the trick.

Also `.split(s -> s.transactional(false))` didn't circumvent this.

**EDIT**:

Forget the flow/queue naming above. This is my Spring Integration code. I think I included the most relevant beans here.

1. The first stage creates empty messages from a poller. These are kind of the events that trigger a request to a feed (50 items in json).
   Each of the 50 items (split) is saved in the first rabbit queue.
2. Then the second stage starts (incoming amqp messages are dropped in myChannel2). Via myChannel3 and myChannel4 it eventually is persisted in the second rabbit queue.

These two stages are handled kind-of in parallel. I see that FIRST_RABBIT_QUEUE gets filled every time with 50 new messages.
I also see that the second stage is executed: SECOND_RABBIT_QUEUE get filled (and the counter of the first queue decreases). All fine.
But now the SECOND_RABBIT_QUEUE keeps growing and is never handled by `myFlow3`.

If the first queue grows faster than it is emptied, both queues (first,second) keep growing. When it is however emptied (counter back to zero), the third stage (myFlow3) starts working!

My configuration:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel1() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel2() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel3() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel4() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel5() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel6() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outputAmqpFlow(final AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(AMQP_OUTPUT)
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                    .exchangeName(AmqpConfiguration.TOPIC_EXCHANGE)
                    .routingKeyExpression("headers['queueRoutingKey']"))
            .get();
}


private HeaderValueRouter router() {
    HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE);
    router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.FIRST_RABBIT_QUEUE, "myChannel2");
    router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.SECOND_RABBIT_QUEUE, "myChannel5");
    router.setResolutionRequired(false);
    router.setDefaultOutputChannelName("errorChannel");
    return router;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow routeIncomingAmqpMessagesFlow(final SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer,
                                                     final Queue firstRabbitQueue,
                                                     final Queue secondRabbitQueue,
                                                     final Queue thirdRabbitQueue,
                                                     final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter) {
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(
            firstRabbitQueue,
            secondRabbitQueue,
            thirdRabbitQueue
    );
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Amqp.inboundAdapter(simpleMessageListenerContainer)
                    .messageConverter(jackson2MessageConverter))
            .headerFilter("queueRoutingKey")
            .route(router())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow0() {
    return IntegrationFlows.<MessageSource>from(
            () -> new GenericMessage<>("trigger flow1"),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(getPeriod(), initialDelay)))
            .channel(myChannel1())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel1())
            .handle(String.class, (p, h) -> {
                try {
                    return getLast50MessagesFromWebsite();
                } catch (RestClientException e) {
                    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e);
                }
            })
            .split()
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("queueRoutingKey", AmqpConfiguration.FIRST_RABBIT_QUEUE))
            .channel(AMQP_OUTPUT) // persist in rabbit
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow2_1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel2())
            .handle(this::downloadAndSave)
            .channel(myChannel3())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow2_2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel3())
            .transform(myDomainObjectTransformer)
            .handle(this::persistGebiedsinformatieLevering)
            .channel(myChannel4())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow2_3() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel4())
            .handle(this::confirmMessage)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("queueRoutingKey", AmqpConfiguration.SECOND_RABBIT_QUEUE))
            .channel(AMQP_OUTPUT) //persist in rabbit
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow3() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel5())
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are never enabled by default so I don't think that's the issue (unless you have explicitly enabled them).

What you are describing is very odd. Bear in mind the UI is not real time, it only updates every few seconds, so it's not surprising you see it "jump" from 0 to 50.

> It seems it only acknowledges items after queue1 is entirely empty.

Consumers know nothing about the queue or its contents.

```
.split(s -> s.transactional(false)
```

You should not do that at all; that is enabling transactions (I am surprised it works at all because it should need a transaction manager) but as long as the outbound adapter doesn't have a transactional `RabbitTemplate` it shouldn't matter.

You need to show your flow definitions and any configuration properties for anyone to help further.

Comment: Ok, I shouldn't have call it transactions. I'm familiar with RDMS transactions ending with a commit. I assumed a 'acknowledge' was comparable with a commit. Therefore I called it a transaction...
I'm aware of the UI not being real-time. Are you stating that 50 messages get added piece by piece and are also 'acknowledged' piece by piece?
About consumers knowing the queues: It is my way of saying: the consumer doesn't get into action until the source queue has messages acknowledged.

Comment: There is no "ack" on the publisher side (unless you are using transactions). Published messages are immediately available for consumption (as long as transactions are not being used).

Comment: OK, that is good to know. acknowledgement mode AUTO and no transactions is what I have (and had). After reading TRACE logs I learned that flow2 actually gets started while queue1 gets filled. So that _does_ work in parallel. However flow3 doesn't start although queue2 is filling up. Do you have any idea why this can happen? What makes that Spring integration observes multiple queue's at 'the same time'? Multiple threads? or workers? How can I make sure that, for example, flow2 runs multiple instances in parallel? and how to run flow2 and flow3 in parallel?

Comment: I'd need to see you configuration but there should be nothing to prevent flow3 from consuming messages while flow2 is producing them. The only thing I can think of is, if you are using DirectMessageListenerContainers with a shared task executor with insufficient threads; as [discussed here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#threading).

Comment: Gladly Spring Integration offers the possibility to simplify EIP objects. But often I get confused by complexities behind the scenes like now. I will try to add more configuration details to the question above.

Comment: I added my oconfiguration.

Comment: I don't see you sending anything to `THIRD_RABBIT_QUEUE`.

Comment: I had a SimpleMessageListenerContainer. After replacing it with the DirectMessageListenerContainer (as suggested) my problem was solved! I use the default (?) task executor.

Comment: Removed `THIRD_RABBIT_QUEUE` (out of scope)

Comment: Now I am confused; you said the problem was that flow3 didn't read anything, yet it's reading from `THIRD_RABBIT_QUEUE`. I cannot think of any reason why changing the container type would make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, by adding the configuration I used new names.